# bidirectional OneToOne parent/child behavoiur

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a question concern hibernate: 
Imagine we have  a situation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Address.class)
private List<Address> investments = Collections.emptyList();

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="addresses")
public class Address{

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
private User createdBy;
```

in this situation we have bidirectional relationship. 
In this scenario it is possible to remove only user without touching Addresses?

Because when I try to remove User using entityManager.remove(user) hibernate remove also Addresses connected with this user.

UPDATE:
In above code by default we have 
orphanRemoval = false 
cascadeType = empty

from this parameters when I will try to delete user it should be deleted without address. But this doesn't happend. When I'll delete user it will delete together with address. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

try to do the remove in this way:
// use your setter and getter names

```
    tx = em.getTransaction();   
    tx.begin();  
    User user = em.find(User.class,1);
    Address address = user.getAddress();
    address.setUser(null);
    user.setAddress(null);
    em.merge(address);
    em.remove(em.merge(user));
    tx.commit();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replay...you show me that I wasn't precise with my question. I will update it then.

Comment: and try to remove User as I suggested, then tell me the result